# Generic Deserialize

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, serialization, xml-serialization

Please guide me how to obtain the type from a generic type parameter, in the situation bellow:

```
  Public Function DerializeFromFile(Of T)(ByVal fileName As String) As T
    Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(T.GetType()) '--------------- HELP !!!???
    Dim fileStream = New FileStream(fileName,
                    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
    Dim loadedObject As T = DirectCast(serializer.Deserialize(fileStream), T)
    Return loadedObject
  End Function
```

Comment: It is `typeof(T)` in C#, there must be a similar syntax in VB too. Maybe `TypeOf(T)` ??

Comment: is not typeof in VB, probably GetType...

Comment: Type of vb.net: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to:

```
Dim serializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(T))
```

In VB, the `GetType` operator returns the `Type` object for the given type.